# How can I temporarily plug a toilet drain?

Tags: toilet, drain

I want to temporarily seal a toilet drain so that I can fill and soak the bowl with a solution of hydrochloric acid to remove mineral scale.  The seal has to be water-tight so that the solution can sit for several hours.

I have tried jamming plastic bags and water balloons into the drain but they don't form water-tight seals.

(I found [two](https://toiee.com/) [products](https://www.m3floodtec.com/shop/products/inflatable-toilet-bung-m3tlb), designed for this purpose, consisting of inflatable rubber bladders, but they are only available in the U.K.)

Comment: Quite often design for, can be a name change only.  Those products not much more inflatable bladders.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following hack: I wrapped an air wedge in strips of rubber from a bicycle inner tube like so:
[image: Air wedge wrapped in rubber]

Jamming and inflating it in the toilet drain as in the following photo, the bowl lost less then a cm of water height over the course of three hours.
[image: Air wedge + rubber toilet plug]

Comment: Were you able to remove mineral scale using this hack? Have you found a better way to block the drain?

Comment: @tunafish24 No to both.  I've found that scrubbing with drywall sanding screen is the best way to remove scale from glazed fixtures like toilets.

Comment: Which ingredient & how much did you use when you filled it up water?

Comment: @tunafish24 I tried adding muriatic acid to the water – quite a bit.  I don't know why it didn't work.